# How to use variables to create elements in an array in BASH?

Tags: arrays, bash

I know that in bash:

```
declare array=(hei{1,2}_{1,2})
```

will create an array with a list of elements:

```
echo ${array[*]}
hei1_1 hei1_2 hei2_1 hei2_2
```

but I would like to use variables in the array declaration,too:

```
var=1,2
declare array=(hei{$var}_{$var})
```

But it does not work:

```
echo ${array[*]}
hei{1,2}_{1,2}
```

Please help. I find very frustrating to specify something like hei{1,2}_{a,b,c}..n times..{hei,hei} in a code.

Thanks in advance

**NOTE: It is possible in zsh without eval (got it from [stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90938/possible-to-use-brace-permutation-and-array-expansion-simultaneously)):** 
e.g., this script would do what i need, but in zsh (which I cannot always use):

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
var1=( a c  )
var2=( 1 2  )
arr=($^var1$^var2)
printf "${arr[*]}"
```

Comment: FYI, `${array[*]}` turns your array into a string, and since that string is unquoted, string-splits it and expands any globs within. Using `printf '%q\n' "${array[@]}"` is a safer, more accurate way to display the contents of an array, since it shows you the difference between `array=( "hello world" )`, `array=( hello world )`, and `array=( hello $'world\r' )`.

Comment: Thanks Charles Duffy. I cannot upvote, but thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brace expansion cannot be used with variables unless you also use `eval`, because brace expansion occurs *before* parameter expansion does.

The safe approach (no eval) is thus to not use brace expansion at all:

```
var=1,2
IFS=, read -r -a var_values <<<"$var"
result=( )
for val1 in "${var_values[@]}"; do
  for val2 in "${var_values[@]}"; do
    result+=( "hei${val1}_${val2}" )
  done
done
```

The unsafe approach is something like this:

```
var=1,2
eval "array=( hei{$var}_{$var} )"
```

**DO NOT** follow the latter practice unless you trust your inputs.

Comment: Every cloud has a silver lining: I think Shellshock will make lots of people think twice before using `eval` on their variables. For a while, at least. :)

Comment: Thanks, this works :) I am still not familiar with the order in expansion. In this specific case I trust my inputs, and therefore I am tempted to use eval (and thus it is also the reason why I did not care about using "echo" and quoting them). But to avoid future bugs, I will use the safe approach.

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this...

```
var=1,2
declare -a array

IFS=','
for item in ${var}; do
array[${#array[@]}]="$item";
done
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe there was a misunderstanding: what you suggest is the same as to do declare -a array=(1 2). Instead, I want the all possible combination of the numbers, like declare -a array=(11 12 21 22).